# What is difference between cache and static html?

Tags: wordpress

Do wordpress cache plugin give same result as static html?

I want my wordpress to have the best result on google lightroom.

Is static html always better than caching and optimizing plugin if my VPS is not too fast.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static HTML pages are typically faster than dynamic WordPress pages, even with cache and optimization plug-ins installed.

This is just because of static pages do not require any server-side processing (Like PHP, Java, etc..), whereas dynamic pages (Like PHP, Java, etc..) require the server to generate the page content before it can be served to the user.

That's why static HTML pages are the best option instead of installing plugins inside WordPress like CMS.

Answer (score 0):

For best performance on high traffic site  use an asynchronous Cron scheduled process to periodically generate and serve cached static html files.

Implement Websockets or JavaScript AJAX to Rest API on frontend for real time dynamic UI data updating.

You can easily implement a Websocket server using NodeJS or Python.  On backend use  message queue (MQTT).

There is no reason to dynamically assemble pages from DB or object cache during web server request/response event.